# Can I get faster than 33 ksamples/second for A/D on my Netduino Plus 2?

Tags: adc, netduino

I have a Netduino Plus 2. It looks like if I write a loop doing nothing but sampling one A/D pin 100,000 times, then reporting to the PC via debug statement, I get one report every three seconds or so. So my sample rate is about 33 ksamples/second. If I sample three channels 100,000 times, it takes about nine seconds. So it looks like my 33 ksamples/second are divided among however many channels are being sampled.

I think the ARM controller should be capable of faster sampling than this. Is there any way I can speed up A/D conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Netduino Plus 2 uses the [STM32F405RG](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf) microcontroller. Looking at the datasheet, you should be able to sample *much* faster than 33 kSa/s:
[image]

While slightly reduced performance is to be expected when using any abstraction layer (like the netduino libraries), *180 times* slower sampling is not normal. Do you mind posting the code?

By writing your own ADC code you should be able to take full advantage of the hardware, but there is a considerable drawback: the microcontroller is approaching SoC -level complexity, with the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) having 1731 pages, so the effort might not be always worthwile.

Comment: There are some really good libraries (I lean toward CMSIS-compliant libraries) that can bring the learning curve down to something reasonable.  Even then, there's usually zero need to learn every peripheral at the same time.  Those who shy away from the Cortex M because the book is fat are missing out on something really good.

Comment: Definitely not intimidated by the documentation. I'm a microcontroller engineer by trade. I came to the Plus 2 a little backwards; I wanted to use this chip to write analog to an SD card, and then found it was already on a board! Saved me from laying one out.

Comment: @StephenCollings -- then I'd consider dropping the arduino code and just programming the chip.  Also, take a peek at the STM development boards, like the Discovery Series.  They're a real bargain.